# Mouse move makes div move inverted smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make my div move smoothly inverted with the "ease" effect.

When I hover over the div, I want the image to smoothly move away from the mouse, just like they did with the image of the two toys in the first section of [toyfight.co](http://toyfight.co)'s site.

I've inspected their code and wasn't able to find my answer.

Could any of you provide it?

I've managed to do having a slightly rough movement of the image with the code down below. Also a [link to my project on Codepen](https://codepen.io/salman15/pen/evQVLV). (More minimized [here](https://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/pen/eWpqVb?editors=0010))

**Answer**
This plugin helped me achieve my goal

http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Plugin-For-3D-Perspective-Transforms-On-Mousemove-LogosDistort.html

**HTML**

```
<div class="section-0">
        <div class="phone-container" >
      <div class="phone-front" id="layer-one"></div>
    </div>
 </div>

<section class="section-1 parallax parallax-1">


  <div class="container" id="section-1">



         <div class="text-block animation-element">
        <h1>Gemaakt van het fijnste staal</h1>
        <p>"The volks is the rare kind of phone that I can recommend without reservations."<br> — The Verge</p>
      </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

**JQUERY**

```
  $.fn.smoothWheel = function () {
        //  var args = [].splice.call(arguments, 0);
        var options = jQuery.extend({}, arguments[0]);
        return this.each(function (index, elm) {

            if(!('ontouchstart' in window)){
                container = $(this);
                container.bind("mousewheel", onWheel);
                container.bind("DOMMouseScroll", onWheel);
                currentY = targetY = 0;
                minScrollTop = container.get(0).clientHeight - container.get(0).scrollHeight;
                if(options.onRender){
                    onRenderCallback = options.onRender;
                }
                if(options.remove){
                    log("122","smoothWheel","remove", "");
                    running=false;
                    container.unbind("mousewheel", onWheel);
                    container.unbind("DOMMouseScroll", onWheel);
                }else if(!running){
                    running=true;
                    animateLoop();
                }

            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Your image seems to move smoothly to me. What's the problem?

Comment: The one on ToyFights website seems to have an ease effect, wich makes it really smooth

Comment: I would suggest you do this with CSS transitions, which allow for an easing effect and are much simpler than the same effect with JavaScript.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I tried that but to no avail

Comment: Then, I don't think you did it properly.

Comment: I know that's why I posted this, so someone could explain to me how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.css()` instead of `.offset()` on line 358.

So from:

```
$(target).offset({ top: y ,left : x });
```

to:

```
$(target).css({ top: y ,left : x });
```

The overall effect is a lot smoother. CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/pen/MmaNBz?editors=0010).